# 3 monitors windows xp

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, display

I have a laptop mounted to a dock. When I try to use 2 monitors using dualview everything works fine I get my image across 2 monitors, but when I connect the third one I can't use it although its recognized.

Here's what I'd like to do, I'd like to get dual view from my laptop across two monitors, and I have a remote machine connecting to it via remote desktop. I'd like to have that displayed on the third monitor. Is that possible? or some other combination?

**Question update :**

Laptop is Dell latitude E6410

Comment: It would help if you posted hardware specs of laptop and dock. Most likely it's not possible but can't tell for sure without specs.

Comment: @ngen I updated my question

Answer (score 1):

I have had no issues using three monitors on XP. I have a HP laptop connected to a docking station with a monitor connected. The third monitor is connected via usb. I remote into another machine via a citrix or VNC and just put that desktop on whichever monitor I want.

Comment: I can detect them but I can choose only either 2 of them but not all three of them. Unlike you , I have plugged all cables into dock

Comment: @c0mrade, the laptop's GPU can only drive two monitors.

Comment: @c0mrade I don't think there is a way to do that, I have three ports on my laptop one VGA, DVI, and S-Video, plus the laptop screen. I can only have 2 different displays up at the same time. If I have 3 two of them are mirrored. You need a USB video card to make what you want work.

Answer (score 1):

the graphics card in your laptop will not support 3 monitors. I know this as I have the same laptop with the same problem. You will need a hardware improvement to make 3 monitors work. There are a variety of USB to VGA/DVI external video cards I would look into.

Good luck!